# Can't see files on my cell phone

Tags: files, mount, usb, nautilus, file-manager

I have Samsung Galaxy S2 as my cell phone and Debian Squeeze as my desktop. When I connect them using USB, Debian recognize it and allows to open it with file manager. Problem: it displays only directories, all files are like somehow, magically, hidden. I know that they exists, because I can easily see them on Windows 7. I tried to disable file-hiding and related stuff in Nautilus options, but nothing.

Why is that so and how can I see those files?

P.S. I wasn't sure where to post it - in here or in https://android.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Is the output of `ls -l` on the mount point correct? (assuming there is a mount point)

Comment: What did you do on you Android phone after connecting it? Did you mount the USB device to allow the host (Debian) to read the filesystem and SDcard? Usually after you connect your phone, you get a notification "USB Connected". If you click on that, you can `Turn on USB Storage mode` which should allow the host to read the files on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to **turn on USB Storage** from my cell and then mount.